# Can i define multiple URL for an action in one route in Play Framework 2.x?

Tags: controller, playframework-2.0, action, routes

I have two route like these:

```
GET         /admin                       controllers.Application.admin()
GET         /api/admin                   controllers.Application.admin()
```

can i define somthing like this in Play framework 2?

```
GET         /admin        /api/admin                  controllers.Application.admin()
```

Comment: How do you do for reverse routing? Must be a nightmare and I don't think you can define them the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, actually the same action shouldn't have two different routes (also from SEO point of view), therefore best practice is creating a redirect from one of them pointing the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like 
GET         /*res                  controllers.Application.admin(res)

and in controllers you can write 
def admin(res:String)= {
something like this
}
in scala we do this.